# Dynamical systems analysis of deep learning

Tags: reference-request, optimization, machine-learning

I am interested in finding out references that apply dynamical systems analysis to develop the "theory" of deep learning, specifically (say) feedforward deep neural nets. The only paper I seem to have found is "Dynamics of learning in deep linear neural networks" from 2014.

I would like to understand if dynamical systems approach makes sense in developing the theory and analysis of deep learning methods.

Comment: statistical analysis theory & gradient descent concepts are prob more applicable overall/ in general, but also its an emerging area of study...